# flutter app: A problem occurred in create app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have install windows 10 64 bit, Android studio and Visual Studio Code.
I have install Flutter SDK. This is result of "flutter doctor -v" :

```
PS C:\Users\mafer> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19041.330], locale pt-BR)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

But when I'm going to create an app in Visual Studio or Android Studio, I get the following message and the project folders and files are not created correctly.

```
Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
## command
flutter --no-color create --template app --description F2it application. --org com.f2it runners_app
## exception
TemplateException: Value was missing for variable tag: androidFlutterJar. (4:24)
<root url="jar://{{{androidFlutterJar}}}!/" />
```

What went wrong?

Comment: This seems like a case where you should report the bug as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose). Making a new project and copying over the code might be something to try however if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch to master channel or stable channel on your Flutter SDK, [this is how you can do it](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#switching-flutter-channels)

Maybe this will help you out, at least you will know if it is the Flutter version you are using, or something regarding your installation.

Comment: I switch to DEV and now it's OK! tks